# Cloud Armor Ban duration inconsistency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I have set up a cloud armor rule to deny request coming from same ip after n attempts. My config is given below

[rules config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYfEA.png)

I ran jmeter to hit the api continuously with 1 req per second.
start time - 12:37:00
end time - 12:55:00

success api hit timestamp is avialble in the below pic -
[success_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrwOc.png)
[success_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhKXZ.png)

since i am hitting 1 req per sec , all the other request which are not in the above pic sent to the api pic are failures.For ex:

[failure_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAotz.png)
[failure_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygbJK.png)

NOTE :
I did the same testing again from 13:15:34 till 13:35:00. But this time after the first 10 request , i faced ban from 13:15:44 to 13:30:33 and 7-10 request got sucess (attached an image below for this) and then the failure (deny) started again.

[2nd_run_success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZwZP.png)

Questions :

1. How much time does the ban occur for ? For the first run , first ban was for 5 minutes, whereas during the second run , the first ban was for 15 minutes.
2. Inconsistency in response. Randomly during the ban duration instead of getting deny , my api sent a successfull response. This happens only for 1 request and the request after that are getting denied as expected.
3. Inconsistency in Ban duration. First  ban time for an IP is only 5 mins (ban duration config). After that ban duration , 40+ request got successfull , then after 12:43:00 , I am getting api failure till 12:55:00 (for more than 12 minutes). I have stopped the kmeter script at 12:55:00.

Comment: 1) Please edit your post and include the Cloud Armor rule configuration so that we know each parameter name you configured. There are two factors to also consider. How fast the requests are made and the total number of requests per time period. 2) Add details on how you are testing. My recommendation is to write a client to perform the tests so that you have accurate time intervals and repeatable test scenarios.

Comment: @JohnHanley , I have attached the image links which will have more info you required. 
request are made at a speed of 1 req/sec . Total - 1071 requests have been made. Do let me know if you want any other information. Thanks.